# Multiple Windows(AWT) by Using Thread, But Only the Last Window Works

Tags: java

I want to make an imitative hack System. There will be 3 windows displayed on screen.  Each window will show some string Constantly (like some movie scene) . However only the third (the last) window works. So how to make every window show string at the same time?

the frame class as follow:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class sys extends Thread {
    private static Frame frm;
    private static TextArea txa;
    private int fsx, fsy, flx, fly, tsx, tsy, tlx, tly;
    private String strarr[] = new String[7];
    private String frmName;

    public sys(String str, String SAEC[]) {
        frmName = str;
        strarr = SAEC;
    }

    public void SettingFRM(int sx, int sy, int lx, int ly) { 
        //frame's location and size
        fsx = sx;
        fsy = sy;
        flx = lx;
        fly = ly;
    }

    public void SettingTXA(int sx, int sy, int lx, int ly) {
        //textArea's location and size
        tsx = sx;
        tsy = sy;
        tlx = lx;
        tly = ly;

    }

    public void run() {
        frm = new Frame(frmName);
        //the exterior design
        txa = new TextArea("", 100, 100, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_BOTH);
        txa.setBounds(tlx, tly, tsx, tsy);
        txa.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        txa.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        txa.setForeground(Color.green);

        frm.setLayout(null);
        frm.setSize(fsx, fsy);
        frm.setLocation(flx, fly);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        frm.add(txa);

        while (1 != 0) {
            txa.append(strarr[(int) (Math.random() * 7)]);// to obtain new string
            frm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            try {
                sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main program as follow:

```
public class ImitativeHackSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //specific string
        String strarr[] = new String[9];
        strarr[0] = new String("Hacking... Time estimate 25 seconds...\n");
        strarr[1] = new String("Retrying...\n");
        strarr[2] = new String("Error! Code:e2130443523\n");
        strarr[3] = new String("Success! IP:192.168.0.1\n");
        strarr[4] = new String("picking datas...\n");
        strarr[5] = new String("Anti-system started\n");
        strarr[6] = new String("Has been discovering... fake random IP address\n");
        strarr[7] = new String("01011010000011001000000011111101010");
        strarr[8] = new String("111101010101001101101101010011010");

        //object array
        sys fhs[] = new sys[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            fhs[i] = new sys("Fake Hacking System", strarr);

        fhs[0].SettingTXA(635, 690, 5, 30);
        fhs[0].SettingFRM(640, 720, 0, 0);

        fhs[1].SettingTXA(635, 330, 5, 30);
        fhs[1].SettingFRM(640, 360, 645, 0);

        fhs[2].SettingTXA(635, 330, 5, 30);
        fhs[2].SettingFRM(640, 360, 645, 365);
        //to execute
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            fhs[i].start();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post your code?

Comment: @J_D OK! I posted.

Comment: Try removing the `static` keyword from the declarations of the `Frame` and the `TextArea` .

Comment: @Arnaud Still not works.

Comment: AWT methods and constructors must be called in the AWT event dispatch thread only.  Calling them from any other thread results in unpredictable behavior.  Use [EventQueue.invokeAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to run code in that thread.